# android fill singlechoiceitems dialog with arraylist values

Tags: java, android

I defined an array like,

```
String[] types = {"item0", "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6", "item7", "item8", "item9"};
```

Once I fill it, I use its results to fill an alert dialog with single choice items,

```
AlertDialog.Builder b = new Builder(this);
b.setTitle("Results");

b.setSingleChoiceItems(types, 0, new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
```

problem is that result size is variable and item list is filled always with fixed value. I would like to use an ArrayList but setSingleChoiceItems method doesn't accept it. How to reach it? Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use ArrayList to build your items:

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
items.add("this");
items.add("that");
```

Then convert it to an array when passing it to `setSingleChoiceItems`:

```
b.setSingleChoiceItems(items.toArray(new String[items.size()]), 0, new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { ... });
```

If you wanted to implement a single datasource, you could implement the [Cursor interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) but that might be overkill for this.